# Triggering child method from stateful parent widget flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two files

> Parent.dart and Chid.dart

```
Parent.dart:
------------
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  const Parent ({super.key});

  @override
  State<Parent > createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.addbox),
      onPressed: (){//Call Method from the child},
    ), 
  }
}
```

and

```
Child.dart:
------------
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  const Child ({super.key});

  @override
  State<Child> createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {

void myFunciton()
{
    //do something cool.
}
    
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
        }
    }
```

I can send data from parent to child and call methods from parent to child but what I was looking for is a way to access a child method from the parent. Is there a way to call the method from the child when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change _ChildState to ChildState (remove the underlined) for outside dart file can access it

Then in `parent.dart`, declare a `GlobalKey`, pass it to `Child` widget and call function like this:

```
 class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {

  final key = GlobalKey<ChildState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Child(key: key), //I assume you have a child widget here
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.addbox),
            onPressed: () { //Call Method from the child},
              key.currentState?.myFunciton();
            }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```